# Jovo with Messanger

Tags: jovo-framework

I'm recently started to use Jovo framework to build the App for Google Home device based on Dialogflow. The app is working fine. Now decided to do the integration with Facebook Messenger via Dialogflow. It's working fine. I can trigger the bot to start from the Messenger plus can see the output and so on but have two questions:

1. the output in FB messenger looks like this: [speak]Some text inside[/speak],
   can we remove the SSML tags from the output, is there a way to strip
   those tags before tell() or ask() methods are triggered, I have tried
   using the this.googleAction().setResponseObject() method, have
   checked how to response JSON looks like and then created the object
   to pass with the property fulfillmentText, where I removed those
   tags, it works that way but this is not efficient and looking for sth simpler
2. is there a method to use, sth like setResponseObject() but without alexaSkill() or googleAction "prefix" obj, where we can prepare a custom object so we can send custom JSON response. I'm asking cause I want to use FB Messenger specific output like buttons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons. Is this is possible using JOVO

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of Jovo v2.1 ([read the announcement here](https://www.jovo.tech/news/2019-03-05-jovo-v2-1)), you can build Facebook Messenger chatbots with Jovo using [Dialogflow Integrations](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/dialogflow-integrations).

Regarding your questions:

1) This is fixed with the latest update

2) You can set custom payloads with the new `this.$dialogflow.setCustomPayload('facebook', payload)` helper method

Comment: Hi, thx for the update, since the question was asked a few months ago I managed to write custom helper on my own, just needed to check how the JSON output should look like, so I firstly have checked how custom payload for Facebook looks when generated directly on dialogflow (static output from DF), and then have added a helper that was creating such output on AWS Lambda (Jovo app v1)

Comment: Great to hear that!